# падение теста при наличии более одного метода в классе теста

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

Имеется Api тест:

```php
<?php
namespace tests\auth;

use app\fixtures\UserProfileFixture;
use tests\ApiTester;
use Codeception\Util\HttpCode;

class EmailLoginCest
{
    const URL = '/v1/auth/email-login';
    const LOGIN = 'email@example.com'; /** @see <app_path>/fixtures/data/user_profile.php */
    const PASSWORD = '12345'; /** @see <app_path>/fixtures/data/user.php */

    public function _fixtures()
    {
        return [
            'userProfile' => UserProfileFixture::class
        ];
    }

//    public function login(ApiTester $I)
//    {
//        $data = [
//            'email' => self::LOGIN,
//            'password' => self::PASSWORD,
//        ];
//
//        $I->sendPOST(self::URL, $data);
//        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(HttpCode::OK);
//        $I->seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath('$.result.token');
//    }

    public function wrongUserNameLogin(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $data = [
            'email' => '_' . self::LOGIN,
            'password' => self::PASSWORD,
        ];

        $I->sendPOST(self::URL, $data);
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(HttpCode::UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        $I->seeResponseContainsJson([
            'result' => NULL
        ]);
    }
}
```

если какой-либо из методов закомментирован(или его нет вообще), тогда тест отрабатывает нормально:

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.4.4
Powered by PHPUnit 6.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Tests.api Tests (1) -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
✔ EmailLoginCest: Wrong user name login (0.07s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 222 ms, Memory: 12.00MB

OK (1 test, 2 assertions)
```

Стоит только запустить тест с двумя методами то появляется ошибка(метод login() раскомментирован):

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.4.4
Powered by PHPUnit 6.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Tests.api Tests (2) -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
✔ EmailLoginCest: Login (0.58s)
E EmailLoginCest: Wrong user name login 

In Yii2.php line 346:

  Undefined property: Codeception\Module\Yii2::$connectionWatcher
```

Конфиг codeception.yml:

```
namespace: tests
suites:
    unit:
        path: .
        actor: UnitTester
        modules:
            enabled:
                # add more modules here
                - Asserts
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    suite_class: \PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
    memory_limit: 1024M
    log: true
    colors: true
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    support: tests/_support
    data: tests
modules:
    config:
        Yii2:
            configFile: tests/_config/test.web.php
```

Конфиг tests/api.suite.yml:

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - REST:
        depends: PhpBrowser
        url: http://nginx-host/
    - Yii2:
        part: [fixtures]
        entryScript: web/index-test.php
```

Answer (score 0):

проблема была совсем детская: в кофиге приложения компонент 'db' подключался через require_once и соответственно при вызове второго метода теста в db был true. Поменял на require все заработало